# Apache worker processes are not recycled

Tags: apache

Issue: apache child processes are just accumulating over time and keep sitting in process tree. I would expect them to be flushed by root process to keep them behind limits but it turns out new processes just keep adding which ends up with memory swapping etc.

Apache version: 2.4.16

MPM worker config

```
   StartServers            2
   MaxClients            1500
   MinSpareThreads        25
   MaxSpareThreads        75
   ThreadsPerChild        25
   MaxRequestsPerChild  8000
   ServerLimit 600
```

How can diagnose that the apache worker process which is sitting in memory is health or stuck?
What might be the reason of apache not re-using existing processes but spawning new ones?

Thanks